# Security and login on a Symfony 2 based project

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication

I'm developing a web application based on the Symfony 2 PHP framework.

It has a login page for the users registered. I want to execute some custom logic for every user logging into the system.

Basicaly, I want to log whenever any user logs into the system, but I don't want to do it on the main page's controller, because it would log every time the user reloads the main page.

I also want to implement a function that gets called when the user logs into the system so I can decide wether the access is granted or not for any user (based on a full set of information stored on the user's database).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This place is better to give actual problems rather than a "help me" question. If you are having issues with a particular piece of code - fire away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the first part of your question, I had something similar (eg store the last date & time of a user's login). I went down the route of a service which was fired upon an event. In your services config (XML example here):

```
<services>

    <service id="my.login.listener" class="My\OwnBundle\Event\LoginEventListener">
      <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="security.interactive_login" />
    </service>

</services>
```

and then create the above mentioned class in the appropriate place in your bundle:

```
namespace My\OwnBundle\Event;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use My\OwnBundle\User\User as MyUser;

class LoginEventListener
{
    /**
     * Catches the login of a user and does something with it
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $token = $event->getAuthenticationToken();
        if ($token && $token->getUser() instanceof MyUser)
        {
            // You can do something here eg
            // record the date & time of the user's login
        }
    }
}
```

I would imagine that you could extend this to the second part of your question, however I've not done this :-)

Comment: Works great! I appreciate that :)