# Symfony2 Login and Security

Tags: security, authentication, symfony

Is there a way I can store when was the last time a user logged in?

I'm using symfony2, and everything's working alright with the security configuration.

I've seen this [Security and login on a Symfony 2 based project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144446/security-and-login-on-a-symfony-2-based-project), which is a similar question, but it just doesn't fit my needs.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Can you tell us why it didn't fit your needs? What else would you need to do? Services would definitely be my pick for something like this...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create an `AuthenticationHandler` that Symfony will call when user login successfully, you can save the login time into a `User` entity property (supposing that you have this scenario).

First, create the success authentication handler:

```
namespace Acme\TestBundle\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;

class AuthenticationHandler extends ContainerAware implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $token->getUser()->setLoginTime(new \DateTime());
        $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager()->flush();

        return new RedirectResponse($this->container->get('router')->generate('login_success'));
    }
}
```

Then you need to register the authentication handler as a service in a configuration file, for example, `src/Acme/TestBundle/resources/Config/services.yml`

```
services:
    authentication_handler:
        class: Acme\TestBundle\Handler\AuthenticationHandler
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]
```

And configure the login form to use the created handler, check out your `security.yml`

```
form_login:
    success_handler: authentication_handler
```

Obviously, for this to work, you need to have a `User` entity with a `loginTime` property and the corresponding setter. And you need to configure the login to use the `User` entity repository as user provider and the `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, as explained here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#loading-users-from-the-database.

Comment: You missed the `persist()` call in the Handler before `flush()`

Comment: Mmmm... I don't think that `persist()` is necessary since the `User` object getted  via the `User` repository is already managed by the Doctrine entity manager. Check this http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork.html#how-doctrine-keeps-track-of-objects.

Comment: In your example you redirect user to 'login_success' path. I'm using 'target_path_parameter' in my login form. How can I redirect user to the page he was about to go (I don't know if it's admin page, product page, etc.)?

Comment: You have the `$request` parameter on `onAuthenticationSuccess`, you can check that request to get the form parameter, using something like this: `$request->request->get('target_path_parameter')`.

Answer (score 5):

A quite simple solution would be to implement [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) in your application as each user entry in the database has (amongst other things) a "last_login" field.