# Website doesn't run on the server with symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a program in symfony2 and I have a apache server with Cpanel

The project works fine in the local but when I upload it on the server it gives me this error:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 ServiceNotFoundException: The service "security.firewall.map.context.secured_area" has a dependency on a non-existent service "authentication_handler".

in /home/doobin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 59
at CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processReferences(array(object(Reference), object(Reference), object(Definition), object(Definition), 'secured_area', object(Reference), object(Definition), array('check_path' => '/user/login_check', 'use_forward' => false, 'username_parameter' => '_username', 'password_parameter' => '_password', 'csrf_parameter' => '_csrf_token', 'intention' => 'authenticate', 'post_only' => true), object(Reference), object(Reference))) in /home/doobin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 43
at CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processDefinition(object(Definition)) in /home/doobin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 54
at CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processReferences(array(object(Definition), object(Definition), object(Definition), object(Definition), object(Definition), object(Definition), object(Definition))) in /home/doobin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 52
at CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processReferences(array(array(object(Definition), object(Definition), object(Definition), object(Definition), object(Definition), object(Definition), object(Definition)), object(Definition))) in /home/doobin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 43
at CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processDefinition(object(Definition)) in /home/doobin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 37
at CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in /home/doobin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/Compiler.php line 119
at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder)) in /home/doobin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php line 453
at ContainerBuilder->compile() in /home/doobin/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 950
at Kernel->buildContainer() in /home/doobin/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 859
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in /home/doobin/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 571
at Kernel->boot() in /home/doobin/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 614
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in /home/doobin/public_html/app_dev.php line 28
```

I don't know what to do?\
I have given the right permission to cache and log directories and edited the config of the local IP but no change in error!

Any help is appritiated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that It cannot find your authentication service.

Read this, this might help you clean up your security.yml

[Symfony2 Login and Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922516/symfony2-login-and-security)

Like you have mentioned;

You require an authentication handler services.yml like this.

```
services:
    authentication_handler:
        class: Acme\TestBundle\Handler\AuthenticationHandler
        calls:
             - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]
```

And the correct way to write the security.yml is;

```
security:
    firewalls:
        admin_area:
            form_login:
                success_handler: authentication_handler
```

And before uploading your project to a server, clear your dev-cache and test your dev(web/app_dev.php).

Then move to production and clear its prod-cache and test. You won't be facing those errors in a server if you have testing it locally properly (web/app.php).

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ app/console container:debug | grep authentication_handler
```

If result empty then you haven't configured service

Comment: would you please give me more details? I didn't get it well

Comment: Your error message tells you, that the service `authentication_handler` is missing. You can list all registered services with `$ app/console container:debug` and filter the output with `| grep authentication_handler`. So if it isn't listed there, that might be your problem.