# Symfony2 FOSbundle: record every user login date

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

How do I store record every time a user logged in in Symfony2?

I created UserLog entity where I want to record id of record, user's id and date of login.

I am using FOS user bundle for user management. I saw question of recording only last login for every user [Symfony2 Login and Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922516/symfony2-login-and-security) , but couldn't figure out how to record every login date

Comment: the selected answer in the question youve posted has everything you need.  What have you tried and whats going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement an `AuthenticationHandler` which listen on the `onAuthenticationSuccess` event.

First, create the `lastLogin` field in your User entity (datetime, nullable), with getters and setters.

Then, create the  like follows :

```
<?php

namespace Acme\TestBundle\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;

class AuthenticationHandler extends ContainerAware implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();
        $lastLogin = new \DateTime();

        $user->setLastLogin($lastLogin);
        $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager()->flush();

        // redirect the user for example
        return new RedirectResponse($this->container->get('router')->generate('login_success'));
    }
}
```

Register it as a service :

```
// app/config/services.yml
services:
    authentication_handler:
        class: Acme\TestBundle\Handler\AuthenticationHandler
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]
```

And configure it as authentication `success_handler` :

```
// app/config/security.yml
# ...
form_login:
    # ...
    success_handler: authentication_handler
```

Hopes this help you.

**EDIT**

Mistake from me, thanks @JasonRoman.

Instead of a `lastLogin` property, create an entity such as `LoginRecord` which contains a `date` property.

```
/**
 * LoginRecord.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_logins")
 */
class LoginRecord
{
    // Identifier

    /** @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date") */
    protected $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Acme\TestBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="loginRecords")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $user;

    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $date;
    }

    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

}
```

Then, add a property called `$loginRecords` in your User entity, representing a one-to-many association with the `LoginRecord` as `targetClass`.

```
// User entity

class User
{
    // ... Your other properties

    /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Acme\TestBundle\Entity\LoginRecord", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"}) */
    protected $loginRecords;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // ...
        $this->loginRecords = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addLoginRecord(LoginRecord $loginRecord)
    {
        $this->loginRecords[] = $loginRecord;
        $loginRecord->setUser($this);

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeLoginRecord(LoginRecord $loginRecord)
    {
        $this->loginRecords->removeElement($loginRecord);
    }


    public function getLoginRecords()
    {
        return $this->loginRecords;
    }
}
```

And, instead of use `setLastLogin` , use `addLoginRecord($date)` to record  the user logins in your `AuthenticationHandler` :

```
function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
{
    $user = $token->getUser();
    $lastLogin = new \DateTime();

    $record = new LoginRecord();
    $record->setDate($lastLogin);

    $user->addLoginRecord($record);
    $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager()->flush();

    // redirect the user for example
    return new RedirectResponse($this->container->get('router')->generate('login_success'));
}
```

Comment: That only records the last login for the user - he wants it to record every date that they've logged in.

Comment: @chalasr I've tried your solution. Instead logging last login, I tried to record every login: $user = $token->getUser();
        $login_date = new \DateTime();
        $user_log = new UserLog();
        $user_log->setUser($user);
        $user_log->setLoginDate($login_date);
        $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager()->flush();
        return new RedirectResponse($this->container->get('router')->generate('profile', array(
            'user' => $user->getUsername()
        )));   it didn't work. I mean I was logged in and  redirected properly, but data wasn't recorded.

Comment: See my example. You are surely missing the `cascade={"persist"}` in the `$loginRecords` in the User entity and the `setUser($this)` in the addLoginRecord(). Don't forget the constructor too.

Answer (score 3):

> Here is the solution for Symfony4.2

As per [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#authentication-success-and-failure-events) one has to listen to `security.interactive_login` event and create `LoginListener`.

> Code 1

```
app.login_listener:
    class: App\EventListener\LoginListener
    tags:
        - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'security.interactive_login' }
```

> Code 2

```
// src/EventListener/LoginListener.php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

class LoginListener
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        // Get the User entity.
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

        // Update your field here.
        $user->setLastLogin(new \DateTime());

        // Persist the data to database.
        $this->em->persist($user);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

> One has to adjust this example to meet custom needs.

Credit for example `LoginListener` goes to [Rihards Steinbergs](https://rihards.com/2018/symfony-login-event-listener/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override the default authentication handler and do the login there.

1. You will need to create a service of your new authentication handler:

services.yml:

```
    parameters:
    fos_user_security.component.authentication.handler.login_success_handler.class: Path\To\New\Handler



    services:
fos_user_security.component.authentication.handler.login_success_handler:
             class:  %fos_user_security.component.authentication.handler.login_success_handler.class%
             arguments:  [@router, @security.context]
             tags:
                 - { name: 'monolog.logger', channel: 'security' }
```

2. Create the Handler and do the logic:

namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Services;

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;

class LoginSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{

    protected $router;
    protected $security;

    public function __construct(Router $router, SecurityContext $security)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {

        if ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_USER'))

        // create your new entity and add the data you need

        }

        return $response;
    }
```

3. In security.yml you will need to define the new success_handler, something like this:

   ```
   main:
       pattern:             ^/
       context:             user
       form_login:
           provider:       fos_userbundle
           csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
           login_path:     /login
           #use_forward:    false
           check_path:     fos_user_security_check
           success_handler: fos_user_security.component.authentication.handler.login_success_handler // the handler
           #failure_path:   null
           always_use_default_target_path: false
           default_target_path: profile
   ```

Comment: Thanks for solution. I did exactly as you wrote, but got this error: The service "security.firewall.map.context.main" has a dependency on a non-existent service "fos_user_security.component.authentication.handler.login_success_handler". How do you think might be a problem?

Comment: There might be several problems. Which Symfony version are you using?

Comment: Symfony version 2.7.3